# convert all excel files to pdf in their own subfolder vba

Tags: excel, vba

ı would like to convert all excel files to pdf as the whole workbook in subfolders to their original subfolders

I have one solution but my computer is limited. so PowerShell is not supported
[How can I convert .XLS & .XLXS files to .PDF format and return them to each original subfolder in Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452545/how-can-i-convert-xls-xlxs-files-to-pdf-format-and-return-them-to-each-orig)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it.

```
http://www.rondebruin.nl/copy5_3.htm


Sub Convert_Excel_To_PDF()
    Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
    Dim MyFiles() As String, Fnum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim ErrorYes As Boolean
    Dim LPosition As Integer

    'Fill in the path\folder where the Excel files are
    MyPath = "c:\your_path_here\"

    FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
    If FilesInPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Fnum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        Fnum = Fnum + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To Fnum)
        MyFiles(Fnum) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    If Fnum > 0 Then
        For Fnum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(Fnum))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then


                    LPosition = InStr(1, mybook.Name, ".") - 1
                    mybookname = Left(mybook.Name, LPosition)
                    mybook.Activate
                    'All PDF Files get saved in the directory below:
                    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
                        "C:\Documents and Settings\shuerya\Desktop\PDFFiles\" & mybookname & ".pdf", _
                        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
                        :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

            End If

            mybook.Close SaveChanges:=False

        Next Fnum
    End If

    If ErrorYes = True Then
        MsgBox "There are problems in one or more files, possible problem:" _
             & vbNewLine & "protected workbook/sheet or a sheet/range that not exist"
    End If

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: this doesn't solve the issue. It even didn't see any files in subfolders. I also would like to convert excel file to pdf as their source subfolders. so this macro is not avaliable